# How ReentrantReadWriteLock interacts with Java memory model

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to debug an issue that occurred in my program. If there was a data synchronization error across threads, that would explain what I'm seeing. But I'm not certain if there is a data synchronization error lurking in the code or not. I am struggling to find solid information on how `ReentrantReadWriteLock`s interact with the Java memory model, and the information I can find I'm struggling to apply.

I'm pretty sure the order of events are:

1. Thread A acquires the write lock
2. Thread A increments a `long` variable (non-volatile)
3. Thread A releases the write lock
4. Thread B acquires the write lock
5. Thread B releases the write lock
6. Thread B reads the `long` variable

What I am seeing would be explained if at step 6, Thread B is seeing the old stale value of the variable.

However, I think the write lock forms a synchronization lock, and because Thread A releases the write lock before Thread B acquires it, it should see the new value?

Comment: The read isn't synchronized, so it can be reordered, stale, etc. You need to put the read inside the lock, not "after" it.

Comment: Note: If thread B is only _reading_ the variable, you can acquire the _read_ lock to read it rather than the write lock.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not certain if there is a data synchronization error lurking in the code or not.

There is no way to tell from just the information you have given. *If* events are *guaranteed* to happen in the order that you gave—that is to say, *if* you can prove a chain of "happens before" relationships—then thread B would be guaranteed to see the value that was written by thread A, but you have not explained why you think the events will happen in that order.

E.g., What, in your program, prevents this from happening instead?

1. Thread B acquires the lock
2. Thread B releases the lock
3. Thread A acquires the lock
4. Thread A updates the variable while thread B concurrently reads the variable.
5. Thread A releases the lock.

If your program lets that happen, then there's a race condition, and the outcome is not guaranteed. If your program doesn't let that happen, then there's something else in it that you haven't told us about. You can't guarantee that the threads will do their things in a particular order by just using the one lock.

Comment: I’m investigating an issue that occurred. I know the order of the events because I can see them in the logs.